# max_vel_theta not honored by TrajectoryPlannerROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

move_base tries to turn my robot too fast, although I believe that I set limits correctly.

My questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong ?
- Is this a bug ?
- What is the solution ?

My parameter file is:

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.07
  min_vel_x: 0.04
  max_vel_theta: 0.4
  min_vel_theta: -0.4
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.2

  acc_lim_theta: 0.2
  acc_lim_x: 0.2
  acc_lim_y: 0.2

  holonomic_robot: false
```

I have checked by rosparam and rqt_reconfigure that the limits on theta are being set correctly.

The problem seems to be that in-place rotations always emit cmd_vel with theta of 1.0:

```
linear: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 1.0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245309/max_vel_theta-not-honored-by-trajectoryplannerros-?/) by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2016-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its probably the in-place rotations by rotate recovery. Set [max_rotational_vel](http://wiki.ros.org/rotate_recovery#TrajectoryPlannerROS_Parameters) to change that.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on 2016-10-11**:
Yes, that was exactly the problem.  Thank you very much.

I added max_rotational_vel=0.4 to base_local_planner_params.yaml and angular.z was limited correctly. I had not seen that parameter in rqt_reconfigure and did not know it existed.